# Use DroidText for barchart

Tags: itext, android-droidtext

I am just trying different pdf making library for some research in android. I have one question regarding this.  How can we make bar charts , pi charts using droidtext as PdfGraphics2D is not available. Not from itext, I already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a chart library like achartengine (https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) or afreechart (https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/) to create the chart and save it as an image. Afterwards add the image file to the pdf.

There are currently no plans to add PdfGraphics2D support to droidText.